# Android onCreateOptionsMenu findItem get null

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, oncreateoptionsmenu

I'm new to android development. I created a new project with android studio default project template, Navigation Drawer Activity.

I added debug message as follow:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem navCamera = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_camera);

    if(navCamera != null) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Not null");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Why I can't get the menu item object?

Main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Comment: add your R.menu.main file

Comment: Paste your menu.xml here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about above answer, I don't read your question exactly. You can find `NavigationView` in `onCreate()` and set icon using your lib

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    //other stuff here
    ...
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // get menu from navigationView
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    // find MenuItem you want to change
    MenuItem nav_camara = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_camara);

    // set new title to the MenuItem
    nav_camara.setTitle("NewTitleForCamera");
    // Set your icon menu here

    // do the same for other MenuItems
    ....

    // add NavigationItemSelectedListener to check the navigation clicks
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried and still not run the Log.d statement. It's still null

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Why I can't get it in onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: In `onCreateOptionsMenu` with `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`, you can see with this menu, don't have layout `activity_main_drawer.xml`. `activity_main_drawer.xml` in `NavigationView`, you have to find `MenuItem` in this layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with menu item use **onNavigationItemSelected** function as given below.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        R.id.nav_camera:
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Not null");
        break;
    }
}
```

and **onCreateOptionsMenu** as follow:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use iconify to set an icon to menu.

Comment: @bns can you please elaborate above comment, because according to me you must get the justified answer based on your question.

Comment: I want to use the iconify, https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify, to set the icon on menu item. To achive this, it said it seems to use the following code---
menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIcon(
   new IconDrawable(this, FontAwesomeIcons.fa_share)
   .colorRes(R.color.ab_icon)
   .actionBarSize());

which introduce me the above problem